# Controlling 7 segment displays from Arduino + 2 buttons

Tags: arduino

I am a beginner with Arduino and I need your help.

My program needs to start a counter (with a 2 digit 7 segment display) when I push a button (start). It also needs to pause when I push the second button (pause).  If I push the start button again it should resume the count.

My problem is that when I push the start button to resume counting after pausing nothing seems to happen; it stays paused. I can't see why it's not restarting.

**Code:**

```
 void loop()
  {
      s_start=0;    //start button stat
      s_pause=0;    //pause button stat
      s_start=digitalRead(start);
      s_pause=digitalRead(pause);
      int j=0;
    if  ((s_start==1)&&(s_pause==0))
     {
       for (int i=j;i<100;i++)       //count from 1 to 99
        {
         s_pause=digitalRead(pause);   
          if (s_pause==1){
          break;
          display_number(i);     //call display_number function

                 }
        j=i;
        display_number(i)
          }
     }
 }
```

Comment: Better post in the arduino stack exchange side. You'd probably have a better audience

Comment: I would suggest writing out the values of s_start and s_pause to the serial port right before your first if statement and verify they are set to what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots way to control Seven Segment Display using arduino. Here is one URL i want suggest where you will find you code circuit diagram and more .....
http://arduinoworks.com/7-segment-display-with-arduino-interface/

I believe it will help you. From this Site you also will able to find different types of arduino Projects. 
Base Link : >> http://arduinoworks.com/

Comment: A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please [add context around the link](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8259/169503) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. Take into account that being barely more than a link to an external site is a possible reason as to [Why and how are some answers deleted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).